# Book on structure of the unit group of group rings

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, reference-works

I am looking for a book named "The structure of the unit group of group rings" by Dennis, R.K. ,  Lecture Notes in Pure and Applied Math. vol 26, Marcel Dekker, New York, 1977.

This book is referred in a bibliography of Sehgal's book, "Topics in group rings", and I wanted to look what topics and theory has been covered in Dennis' book.

After hours of googling , I couldn't find any trace of it. If someone can point me to some place where I can find it, it will be a huge help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this is not a book but a paper in a book:

> Dennis R.K., The structure of the unit groups of group rings, In: *Ring Theory II*, (Pro. Sec. Conf. Univ. Oklahoma, Norman, Oklahoma, 1975), edited by Bernard R. McDonald and Robert A. Morris, pp 103–130, Marcel Dekker, New York, 1977. [[Zbl 0338.00004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0338.00004)]

Your best bet at finding this is a university library.